# C Memory corruption using static arrays

Tags: arrays, c, struct, memory-corruption

In my Restuarnt project I have 2 arrays of structs. One to represent the menu, second to represent the tables:

```
#define MAX_CATEGORY_NUM 10
#define MAX_ITEMS_PER_CATEGORY 20
#define MAX_NAME_LEN 20
#define MAX_FREE_TEXT_LEN 50
#define MAX_ITEMS_FOR_TABLE 100
#define MAX_TABLES 20

typedef struct {
    char name[MAX_NAME_LEN];
    int count;
    int price;
    char freeText[MAX_FREE_TEXT_LEN];
}item;
typedef struct {
    char categoryName[MAX_NAME_LEN];
    item itemList[MAX_ITEMS_PER_CATEGORY];
}category;
typedef struct {
    item list[MAX_ITEMS_FOR_TABLE];
    int numOfItems;
    double totalPrice;
}table;


void add(category menu[]){
    strcpy(menu[0].categoryName, "Meat");
    strcpy(menu[0].itemList[0].name, "Stack");
    menu[0].itemList[0].price = 100;
}
void save(category menu[]){
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen("Menu","w+b");
    fwrite(&menu, sizeof(category), MAX_CATEGORY_NUM, fp);
    fclose(fp);
}
void load(category menu[]){
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen("Menu","r+b");
    fread(&menu, sizeof(category), MAX_CATEGORY_NUM, fp);
    fclose(fp);
}
int main() {
    category menu[MAX_CATEGORY_NUM];
    table tables[MAX_TABLES];
    
    add(menu);
    save(menu);
 
    return 0;
}
```

Next run:

```
int main() {
    category menu[MAX_CATEGORY_NUM];
    table tables[MAX_TABLES];
    
    load(menu);
    printf("Category is: %s. Item is: %s. Price is: %d\n", menu[0].categoryName, menu[0].itemList[0].name, menu[0].itemList[0].price);
 
    return 0;
}
```

The result:

```
Category is: . Item is: . Price is: 0
```

But if I define the tables arr first and menu arr second, then add and save, its works fine and i get:

```
Category is: Meat. Item is: Stack. Price is: 100
```

Whay this is happening?

Comment: `menu+sizeof(menu)` becomes `(char *)menu + (sizeof(menu)*sizeof(*menu))` thanks to pointer arithmetic. Same for `tables`

Comment: Thank's @aragaer. After casing I got ``` 6405840 -> 6422040  
6245520 -> 6405840 ```  But this make things worse for me.. Now I dont know what the problem is. Why there is a different if i define tables first the program runs fine and if menu first not?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Can you paste some runnable code?

Comment: You cannot print a pointer with `%d` conversion specifier, it is undefined behaviour. "Meaning that there is a Memory corruption" Nope, it doesn't mean anything like that. "Now I dont know what the problem is" We don't know either. You are not telling us why you decided that there is a problem in the first place. You only said "I have faced an issue" but what *is* the issue?

Comment: @alinsoar I edit the question

Comment: Post a [mre] (please make sure it is indeed minimal and reproducible).

Comment: It is not enough to edit. You need to do what the others already said, to put here a code example that we can compile and execute.

Comment: @alinsoar I edit the question. hope its better now. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Replace *&menu* with *menu* in your fread and fwrite calls.   If you want to see why, write a test program like: `void f(int r[]) { printf("%p, %p\n", r, &r); }
main() { int r[10]; f(r); }`

Answer (score 1):

As @mevets says.. To fwrite an array of struct just pass the array menu. Only if you pass a single struct then use **&** category

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).